# If a query fails in an EVENT, does the EVENT fail?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

Is it safe to assume that if a query within an `EVENT` returns not `OK`, the `EVENT` will fail immediately?

`DELETE` is destructive, so I want to make sure that the previous query succeeds before the (same records) are `DELETEd`.

```
use argus_dnsdb;
DELIMITER |
CREATE EVENT `dnsdb_rotator`
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:05')
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE
ENABLE
DO BEGIN
set @target_table_name=CONCAT('`argus_dnsdb`.`',date_format(date_sub(now(),interval 1 day), '%Y%m%d'),'`');
set @create_table_stmt_str = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ',@target_table_name,' like `argus_dnsdb`.`main`;');
PREPARE create_table_stmt FROM @create_table_stmt_str;
EXECUTE create_table_stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE create_table_stmt;
set @a=unix_timestamp(date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00'));
set @insert_stmt_str = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ',@target_table_name,' SELECT * FROM `argus_dnsdb`.`main` WHERE qtime < ',@a,' ;');
PREPARE insert_stmt FROM @insert_stmt_str;
EXECUTE insert_stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE insert_stmt;
DELETE FROM `argus_dnsdb`.`main` WHERE qtime < @a ;
END;
|
DELIMITER ;
```

In this instance, if `EXECUTE insert_stmt;` fails, will the `EVENT` stop executing the `DO` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the type of error. [As stated in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare-handler.html):

> If *[an error]* condition occurs for which no handler has been declared, the
>   action taken depends on the condition class:
>
> For SQLEXCEPTION conditions, the stored program terminates at the
>   statement that raised the condition, as if there were an EXIT handler *[i.e. the program returns]*.
>   If the program was called by another stored program, the calling
>   program handles the condition using the handler selection rules
>   applied to its own handlers.
>
> For SQLWARNING conditions, the program continues executing, as if
>   there were a CONTINUE handler.
>
> For NOT FOUND conditions, if the condition was raised normally, the
>   action is CONTINUE. If it was raised by SIGNAL or RESIGNAL, the action
>   is EXIT.

A failed insertion raises an `SQLEXCEPTION`, so the program terminates (or triggers a custom error handler, if such handler exists).

(the definitions for `SQLEXCEPTION`, `SQLWARNING` and `NOT FOUND` are provided in the same manual page)

Comment: Perfect thanks!  `DECLAREing` an `EXIT HANDLER` to handle specific `SQLSTATEs` would be another option, but unnecessary in this case.  Bounty will be awarded in 3 hours due to system limitation.